# Getting Cannot access a closed file error

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I use the following code to iterate a collection of files that I need to copy from one folder to another. It works fine when the source file exist, but when it does not exist I get

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file. at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen() at System.IO.FileStream.get_Position()

What am I missing here?

```
For Each itm In listOfFiles
    Try
        If File.Exists(itm.SourcePath + itm.FileName) Then

            Dim cf As New FileStream(itm.SourcePath + itm.FileName, FileMode.Open)
            Dim ct As New FileStream(itm.DestinationPath + itm.FileName, FileMode.Create)
            Dim len As Long = cf.Length - 1
            Dim buffer(1024) As Byte
            Dim byteCFead As Integer
            While cf.Position < len
                byteCFead = (cf.Read(buffer, 0, 1024))
                ct.Write(buffer, 0, byteCFead)
                fileCopyProgressBar.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() fileCopyProgressBar.Value = CInt(cf.Position / len * 100)))

            End While
            ct.Flush()
            ct.Close()
            cf.Close()

            itm.FileExsits = True

        Else
            itm.FileExsits = False
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        log.Error(ex.Message & "  (unc)")
    End Try
Next
```

Comment: where does it throw?

Comment: This is the error I get on the server that run the application..

System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
   at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
   at System.IO.FileStream.get_Position()

Comment: which line number?

Comment: He meant which line? While debugging, remove the `Try ... Catch` block so you could detect the faulting line.

Comment: You're calling `BeginInvoke` but not `EndInvoke`. Not doing so will cause thread and memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calculating value before putting it in the action. You should also dispose of the streams when done with them

```
For Each itm In listOfFiles
    Try
        If File.Exists(itm.SourcePath + itm.FileName) Then
            Using cf As New FileStream(itm.SourcePath + itm.FileName, FileMode.Open)
                Using ct As New FileStream(itm.DestinationPath + itm.FileName, FileMode.Create)
                    Dim len As Long = cf.Length - 1
                    Dim buffer(1024) As Byte
                    Dim byteCFead As Integer
                    Dim percentage As Integer
                    While cf.Position < len
                        byteCFead =(cf.Read(buffer, 0, 1024))
                        ct.Write(buffer, 0, byteCFead)
                        percentage = CInt(cf.Position / len * 100)
                        fileCopyProgressBar.BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() fileCopyProgressBar.Value = percentage))
                    End While

                    ct.Flush()
                    ct.Close()
                    cf.Close()
                End Using
            End Using

            itm.FileExsits = True
        Else
            itm.FileExsits = False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        log.Error(ex.Message & "  (unc)")
    End Try
Next
```